# How To get transaction details in commerce checkout complete page

Tags: commerce

Can anyone please help to get the transaction details in commerce checkout complete page. I could get using hook_commerce_checkout_complete($order). I can show the success/Error transaction and order details in drupal_set_message. But Exactly I need show in checkout complete page instead of message box. Please help how to do. Thank you.

Comment: Please tag which version of Drupal you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for Drupal 7, you could do the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function  MODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_complete_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $order_id = $form_state['order']->order_id;
  // Use the entity field query to get transaction entities.
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_payment_transaction')
    ->propertyCondition('order_id', $order_id);
  $result = $query->execute();
  if (!empty($result) && !empty($result['commerce_payment_transaction'])) {
    // Load the Payment Transactions
    $transactions = commerce_payment_transaction_load_multiple(array_keys($result['commerce_payment_transaction']));
    $form['payment_status']['#markup'] = '<h2>' . t('Payment Pending') . '</h2>';
    foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
      if ($transaction['status'] == "success") {
        $form['payment_status']['#markup'] = '<h2>' . t('Payment Received!') . '</h2>';
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    $form['payment_status']['#markup'] = '<h2>' . t('Error. No Payment Transactions.') . '</h2>';
  }
}
```